502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.27.3 Laravel Herd PHP 8.2 macOS Sonoma
I have tried to deploy the Laravel application using Nginx web server. However, I get the 502 Bad Gateway error. What could be the reason? Is it permission issue or something else.
Following code snippet shows the default site configuration file.
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    error_log /opt/homebrew/var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /opt/homebrew/var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name dev.easysell.local;

        root /Users/hassanali/Development/server/laravel/projects/easysell-laravel/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/Users/hassanali/Library/Application\ Support/Herd/herd82.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }
    }

    # Uncomment or modify as needed
    # include servers/*;
}


The following commands helped me:

brew unlink php && brew link php
brew services restart --all
composer global update
valet start
valet install

